# SHOWPLAN permission denied when including execution plan in Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

If I select the "Include execution plan" checkbox in the Data Explorer, the query fails:

> SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'StackOverflow'.

[image]

I see that [this has happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212979/data-explorer-execution-plans-are-no-longer-available-because-showplan-permissio) following maintenance. I don't know whether there was any recent maintenance. It's been several days since the data was updated and longer since an update was deployed, if that's related.

Comment: There was a security incident reported earlier, maybe this has something to do with that..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260416/data-explorer-queries-and-sensitive-information

Comment: I'm now getting the error `The 'CardinalityEstimationModelVersion' attribute is not declared.` if I try to get the query plan against a real table. Different error, but same net result, so I won't open a new question.

Comment: I have a submitted a [PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/70) to get that fixed.

Answer (score 7):

It is annoying but at least the showplan permission has been fixed somewhat by not using the checkbox on the UI but leveraging the [`SHOWPLAN_TEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176058.aspx) setting yourself as part of the command batch:

#### SQL

```sql
set showplan_text  on
go 
select top 10 *
from posts 
inner join votes v on v.postid = posts.id
go
```

#### Result

```
StmtText                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------- 
select top 10 *
from posts inner join
votes v on v.postid = posts.id 

(1 row(s) returned)

StmtText                                                                                                                                                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((10)))                                                                                                                                                                              
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([v].[PostId], [Expr1003]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)                                                                                            
            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([StackOverflow].[dbo].[Votes].[UIX_Votes_Id] AS [v]))                                                                                                            
            |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([StackOverflow].[dbo].[Posts].[UIX_Posts_Id]), SEEK:([StackOverflow].[dbo].[Posts].[Id]=[StackOverflow].[dbo].[Votes].[PostId] as [v].[PostId]) ORDERED FORWARD) 

(4 row(s) returned)
```

I tried this same script earlier (when I left the comment) and at that time this failed as well.

So consider this now as a temporary workaround.